# Can the rcx work without the infrared tower

Tags: mindstorms, rcx

I'm getting a rcx 1.0 or 1.5 and it's not coming with the tower. Can I still program it, using some sort of cable?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. But [IR towers are pretty cheap](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=%20IR%20Transmitter%20Tower), especially the older serial ones (you have to add an USB to serial converter to use the latter version on modern computers)